# T-SQL conversion script to delete bad data from permissions bridge table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-delete

My goal is to write a loop/conversion that will go through each container (acucore_securitycontainer table) and clean up all permissions (acucore_securitypermission bridge table) based on the scripts below.  I don't care if I end up with two scripts.. that's completely fine.  Notice the difference between these two clean-up queries is the "S:" vs. "H:" and "Saliva: " vs. "Hair: ".

**Query #1 (for hair application context security):**

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
WHERE 
    'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
    + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64)) IN
(
    SELECT 
        'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
        + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64))
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername LIKE 'H:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND groupname NOT IN
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN 'Hair: ' + groupname ELSE groupname END AS 'custom groupname'
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
        AND permissions = 1
    )
)
```

**Query #2 (for saliva application context security):**

```
DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
WHERE 
    'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
    + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64)) IN
(
    SELECT 
        'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
        + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64))
    FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    WHERE containername LIKE 'S:UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
    AND groupname NOT IN
    (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN 'Saliva: ' + groupname ELSE groupname END
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername = 'UI.Web.AccessioningDashboard'
        AND permissions = 1
    )
)
```

Comment: am I missing something, don't you have what you need?

Comment: there was no loop.. we have hundreds of containers, so I didn't want to run this twice manually for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.. I just switch out the 2 hair set commands with the 2 saliva.. so I have to run this twice.

```
DROP TABLE #Temp
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp 
FROM dbo.acucore_securitycontainer 
WHERE containername LIKE 'UI.Web.%'

Declare @conversioncontainerid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
Declare @conversioncontainername VARCHAR(64)

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM #Temp) > 0 
BEGIN 

    SELECT TOP 1 @conversioncontainerid = containerid FROM #Temp 
    SELECT TOP 1 @conversioncontainername = containername FROM #Temp 

     ---- start processing for container ----

    DECLARE @containerprefix VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @groupprefix VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @sourcecontainername VARCHAR(64);  -- container from loop
    DECLARE @targetcontainername VARCHAR(64);
    SET @sourcecontainername = @conversioncontainername
    SET @targetcontainername = @conversioncontainername

    -- hair
    SET @containerprefix = 'H:'  -- no space at end!
    SET @groupprefix = 'Hair: '  -- space at end!

    -- saliva
    --SET @containerprefix = 'S:'  -- no space at end!
    --SET @groupprefix = 'Saliva: '  -- space at end!

    -- view exclusion groups (groups of a "good" container):

    --SELECT 
    --  CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN @groupprefix + groupname ELSE groupname END
    --FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    --JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    --JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    --WHERE containername = @sourcecontainername
    --AND permissions = 1

    ---- rows to be deleted:

    --SELECT 
    --  groupname,
    --  containername,
    --  dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid ,
    --  dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid ,
    --  dbo.acucore_securitypermission.permissions      
    --FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    --JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    --JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    --WHERE containername LIKE @containerprefix + @targetcontainername
    --AND groupname NOT IN
    --(
    --  SELECT 
    --      CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN @groupprefix + groupname ELSE groupname END
    --  FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    --  JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
    --  JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
    --  WHERE containername = @sourcecontainername
    --  AND permissions = 1
    --)

    DELETE FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
    WHERE 
        'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
        + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64)) IN
    (
        SELECT  
            'ENTITYID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid as VARCHAR(64)) + '|' 
            + 'ESID:' + cast(dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid as VARCHAR(64))
        FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
        JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
        WHERE containername LIKE @containerprefix + @targetcontainername
        AND groupname NOT IN
        (
            SELECT 
                CASE WHEN groupname IN ('Accessioning', 'Screening', 'Positive Certify', 'Negative Certify', 'Confirmation') THEN @groupprefix + groupname ELSE groupname END
            FROM dbo.acucore_securitypermission
            JOIN dbo.acucore_securitycontainer ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.esid = dbo.acucore_securitycontainer.esid
            JOIN dbo.acucore_securitygroup ON dbo.acucore_securitypermission.entityid = dbo.acucore_securitygroup.entityid
            WHERE containername = @sourcecontainername
            AND permissions = 1
        )
    )      
    -- finish processing 
    DELETE #Temp Where containerid = @conversioncontainerid -- delete row so we don't loop over it again 
END
```